# VS2010 error: Cannot find custom tool 'GlobalResourceProxyGenerator' on this system

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Good day!

My strongly typed resource classes acessible via `Resources.<Name of resx file>` in ASP.NET MVC2 project from `/App_GlobalResources` are not updated anymore.

I've tried to right click on them and choose "Run custom tool" and got error:

```
Cannot find custom tool 'GlobalResourceProxyGenerator' on this system.
```

I use VS2010 Express, project is ASP.NET MVC2 (and uses T4MVC).

Thanks in advance!